# Magento 2 the way to pass array in API function

Tags: magento2, api

I'm using my custom API for getting some entities.
I would like to filter items by Id.
Here is the fragment of `webapi.xml`:

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/opencGCApiGcapiapi/list/:products" method="GET">
        <service class="Openc\GCApi\Api\GcapiapiInterface"  method="list"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="products" force="true">products</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
</routes>
```

I'm using this PHP code for testing:

```
$request = new SoapClient($wsdlUrl, ['version' => SOAP_1_2, 'context' =>context]);                                                              
$result = $request->opencGCApiGcapiapiV1List(array('products' => array(1,2)));
```

In my method I've added logging:

```
public function list($products  = NULL)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info(print_r($products, true));
...
```

In the log file I get the following record:

```
2017-11-02T14:50:48+00:00 INFO (6): Array
```

But I can not get the array contents.

Is it possible to pass arrays into the API's function?

Comment: please, add phpdoc for `list` to question

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "phpdoc"?